# Recursion in PROLOG?

Tags: prolog

Given the following Prolog facts:

```
f(a, [b]).
f(b, [c]).
f(c, [d]).
f(d, [e]).
f(e, []).
```

I need to create a query `xyz(a,Y)` so that I get `Y = [e,d,c,b]`, since a depends on b, which depends on c, etc.
My current query is:

```
xyz(X,Y):-
  f(X,P),
  member(Y,[P]).
```

However, this query for `xyz(a,Y)` only gives me `Y = [b]`, and not b's dependents, etc.

I figured that perhaps I can add these two lines to the end of the query above, but that doesn't work as I would like it to. Since the previous free query successfully retrieves a's dependent b, I was hoping these next two lines could perhaps do the same for b and on. But, I don't think this is a good way to approach it maybe. Maybe recursion is a better idea.

```
f(P,S),
member(Y,[P]).
```

I'm pretty sure that I should add a recursion in the end, but I am not sure how to approach. Can someone help me please?

**(3/4) Edit:**

I was able to successfully solve the issue of single-element lists with @CapelliC approach below. However, I would like to extend this problem so that it works for multiple-element lists, where the Prolog facts now look like:

```
f(a, [b, d]).
f(b, [c]).
f(c, []).
f(d, [e]).
f(e, [f]).
f(f, [g).
f(g, []).
```

In this case, query of `xyz(a,X)` should give me: `X = [b,c,d,e,f,g]`, the element-order doesn't necessarily matter, I can sort that after.

This was the previous code that works for single-lists:

```
xyz(Z, [X|Y]):-
    f(Z,[X]),
    !,
    xyz(X,Y).
    xyz(_,[]).
```

According to @lurker I need to incorporate the member function, but I am having trouble with it. This is my current approach, but it doesn't work and just gives me an empty list as output for everything:

```
xyz(Z, [X|Y]):-
    f(Z,X),
    member(Y,X), // I'm not sure if this should be a 'Y'
    !,
    xyz(X,Y).
    xyz(_,[]).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The query `f(X, P, _)` will always fail because it doesn't match the arity of your facts `f`, which have two arguments. So I don't see how your current `xyz(a, Y)` succeeds. Check for typographical errors in what you're showing.

Comment: @lurker Sorry about that. I'll update my post. I look forward to your response, thank you.

Comment: If `P` is already a list, you don't want `member(Y, [P])`. You want `member(Y, P)`. For example, if `P = [a,b,c]`, then `member(Y, [P])` is true *only if* `Y = [[a,b,c]]`. Not what you want. If you do `member(Y, P)`, then it's true for `Y = a` or `Y = b` or `Y = c`.

Comment: Why are you doing `course(Z, [X])` here? Remember our discussion about lists: if you want the second argument to be a list, you don't put brackets around it as `[X]`, otherwise, you will only match a list of one element, namely, `X`. You just want `course(Z, X)`. Also, things have changed quite a bit and this should have been posted as a new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this snippet get the list in reverse order, wrt your request...

```
xyz(K, [D|Ds]) :- f(K, [D]), !, xyz(D, Ds).
xyz(_, []).
```

*edit* extending to multiple dependency elements (but without loops !) could be done like

```
xyz(K, Ds) :- f(K, DKs) -> findall([T|P], (member(T, DKs), xyz(T, P)), L), flatten(L, F), sort(F, Ds) ; Ds = [].
```

Comment: thank you, I will study your approach. Because of this, I was able to discover the idea of "cuts" to control backtracking. Also I didn't know you could have multiple expressions ending with '.' in one conditional predicate. By the way, I do not need the snippet in reverse order. Quick way to fix that?

Comment: Also, I noticed that even though this works for most test scenarios, it doesn't work for all and gives an empty list instead of the correct list of answers. For example, given these Prolog facts: "f(a, [b, c, d]). f(b, [e]). f(c, [j, g]). f(d, [c, g]). f(e, [h]). f(g, [b]). f(j, [b]). f(h, [ ])." and with your approach, of xyz(a,X), I get X = [ ], when clearly I should get a dense list. Do you know if there's any certain restrictions that may be in your code that cause this? Thank you.

Comment: @am3decoy your original problem statement showed all single-element lists for your facts. You only mentioned multi-element lists in your comment. So your original question is very unclear.

Comment: @lurker thanks for pointing that out. The OP is just a simplified version. There can be multiple elements in the list, thus the the necessity to backtrack for all the elements within that list. Thing is that CapelliC's approach does still work on multiple-element lists, however some of them do not, such as the one I posted in the comments right before you. Do you know where the restriction may be within the provided snippet by CapelliC?

Comment: @lurker I'm trying the following, but I'm getting the same result as before. xyz(Z,[X|Y]):-
 f(Z,[X],(underscore)),
 member([Z],P),
 P \= 0,
 !,
 xyz(X,Y).
 xyz((underscore,[ ]).

Comment: @am3decoy, `member(X, L)` is true if *element* `X` is in the *list* `L`. So `member([Z], P)` is true only if the element `[Z]` is in the list `P`, meaning `P = [..., [Z], ...]`.

Comment: @lurker can you please elaborate? Logically this makes sense to me, do you see where my thought process is incorrect? `xyz(Z, [X|Y]):- f(Z, [X], _),memberchk(Z, [X]),`, so it first 'stores' all of a's (Z) dependents into the list [X] which will contain b, since b is a's dependent. `!, xyz(X, Y). xyz(_, [ ]).` which recursively does the same process with the rest of the dependents.

Comment: @am3decoy looks like you changed your code again since my comment. But to comment on the new code you just showed, `memberchk(Z, [X])` means you are checking for membership of `Z` in a list `[X]` which has only one element, `X`. That's the same as `Z = X`. Your earlier comment indicated you want to have these lists handle multiple members. But `[X]` has only one member. You've accepted CappelliC's answer. I think if you have further questions, you should open a new stackoverflow.com question for it rather than use long comment threads to resolve.

Comment: @lurker I do want it handle multiple members, how do I go about doing that? I am only trying different things, so I shouldn't have prematurely accepted the answer.

Comment: In this case, you want it to match on any possible member, so you'll need `member(E, L)` where `E` is what you want to check, and `L` is the list of things you want to determine if it's a member of.

Comment: @lurker The reason that I have `memberchk(Z,[X])` is because I thought X is in fact a list of multiple elements which are a's dependents. Can you guide me the right direction please? I would create a new post, but this post already has a lot of depth to it and this is very related to the original post. @CapelliC

Comment: @am3decoy that doesn't matter. If `X` is a list, then `[X]` is still a list of *one* element, the list `X`. If `X` is a list, you want `member(..., X)` not `member(..., [X])`. `X` is already understood to be a list and adding the extra brackets makes it a list consisting of one element, another list.

Comment: @lurker that makes much more sense.. I've changed it to `memberchk(Z,X)`, but then I had to change the previous line to 'f(Z,X)' because memberchk was expected X to be a list. But now I get an empty list as the answer for anything that I check. The only part I can think that's causing problems now is that 'Z' shouldn't be a 'Z' at all, it should be something else. I've tried other possibilities, but still no luck. Overall, this is my updated code: `xyz(Z, [X|Y]):- f(Z,X), memberchk(#,X), !, xyz(X,Y). xyz(_,[]).` where for # I have tried Y, [Y], Z, [Z] which no luck.

Comment: @am3decoy I think you need to go off and play with this further with your updated knowledge and work at it for awhile, then come back if you get stuck and post a new question, rather than continuing a thread of questions based upon every little road block that emerges in your trek to solve your problem.

Comment: @lurker I think that's a good idea. I'll touch base later. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @CapelliC Thank you extended your solution for this extended problem! If you don't mind, can you explain what needs to be changed in your code to reverse the list that gets outputted?

Comment: just add a reverse at last position - will need an additional temporary variable