# Reversing a list

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I need help reversing a list.

```
fun(a, [b, d]).
fun(b, [c]).
fun(c, []).
fun(d, [e]).
fun(e, [f]).
fun(f, [g]).
fun(g, []).

xyz(X, Y):- 
    fun(X, Z) -> findall([A|B], (member(A, Z), xyz(A, B)), L),
    flatten(L, F), sort(F, Y); Y = [].
```

The query `xyz(a,X).` gives me `X = [b,c,d,e,f,g].`
However, I would like it to give me `X = [g,f,e,d,c,b]`.

I have tried different attempts at reversing the list, but I am not having any luck.

I have tried adding an additional predicate right after this, but it didn't work either:

```
xyz2(X,Y):-
    xyz(X,Y),
    reverse(Y,Z),
    Z\=0.
```

Credit goes to CapelliC for the approach to the implementation above found at my other post here.
[Recursion in PROLOG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845949/recursion-in-prolog)

Comment: @Boris Sure thing, I'll update the original post. Additionally, I have tried the general way of doing it, but perhaps I am missing something. I tried including `reverse(Y,Y)` in the ends of the code, but that doesn't help.

Comment: `xyz(X, Y):- f(X, Z) -> findall([A|B], (member(A, Z), xyz(A, B)), L), flatten(L, F), sort(F, Y); Y = []. reverse(Y,Z), Z\=0.` I tried that as well, but I feel like I am missing an important detail. I can only have X and Y as my arguments.

Comment: @Boris I have updated the post. Perhaps you can lead me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: The easy solution is: rename your `Y` to `Z`, and at the end say `reverse(Z, Y)`. That's all!

Comment: @Boris I figured that out right after I went over your approach. By the way, I really appreciate you going out of your way to explain that. I need to start using the graph theory I have learned and start applying it to problems.

Comment: I do it in the hope you learn. You can try and give your question a bit more specific title. You don't need to include "Prolog" in the title, this is what tags are meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid some difficult programming, and make your program easier to read by re-defining your problem. Say the `f/2` describes a directed graph, with edges from the first argument to each of the elements in the second argument, so:

```
a ---> b
a ---> d
b ---> c
% etc
```

Then, your question is, which nodes in the graph are reachable from a given node? You can define the solution with the help of [`library(ugraphs)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs).

To make all edges from an `f/2`:

```
edge(From-To) :-
    f(From, L),
    member(To, L).
```

You can now collect the edges, make a graph, and find which nodes are reachable from a starting node:

```
foo(X, L) :-
    findall(E, edge(E), Edges),
    vertices_edges_to_ugraph([], Edges, G),
    reachable(X, G, All),
    once(select(X, All, R)), % remove the node you start from
    reverse(R, L).
```

Per definition, a node is always reachable from itself, so you need to pick it out of the list of reachable nodes.

```
?- foo(a, X).
X = [g, f, e, d, c, b].

?- foo(e, X).
X = [g, f].

?- foo(g, X).
X = [].
```

I don't exactly understand why the order of the elements is significant. This feels a bit like a code smell.

Comment: Thank you. This is my updated code that does what I wanted it to do. `xyz(X, Y):- fun(X, Z) -> findall([A|B], (member(A, Z), xyz(A, B)), L), flatten(L, F), sort(F, Z), reverse(Z,Y); Y = [].`

Comment: @am3decoy yep this is what I was trying to say :) however, this question and this solution are more general than simply reversing a list.